# cordova android how to import custom plugin package .aar

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, aar

My cordova items need to run a third-party integration capabilities of the android, ios platform, but official android SDK provides a .aar package, I do not know how to write it in the plugin's plugin.xml to import, help me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova plugin add external .aar file (not .jar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130838/cordova-plugin-add-external-aar-file-not-jar)